# Marshmallow Runtime Permission crashing app

Tags: android, android-permissions

Hi I have been creating an app that uses google map, and everything is working fine until I learned about Marshmallow needs permissions. And I have been reading up on it and I have gotten it to work when I click a button like this it crashes the app.

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    view = v;
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.check_permission:
            if (checkPermission()) {
                Snackbar.make(view,"Permission already granted.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(view,"Please request permission.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                requestPermission();
            }
            break;
    }
```

But when I tried to call the function on requesting the GPS permission on start of the activity like this

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   checkPermission();
}

private boolean checkPermission(){
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        return true;
    } else {
        requestPermission();
        return false;
    }
}

private void requestPermission(){
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
        Toast.makeText(context,"GPS permission allows us to access location data. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Snackbar.make(view,"Permission Granted, Now you can access location data.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                Snackbar.make(view,"Permission Denied, You cannot access location data.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

This is my LogCat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.gin.runtimepermissions, PID: 9203
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.gin.runtimepermissions/com.example.gin.runtimepermissions.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3699)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.
                  at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:137)
                  at com.example.gin.runtimepermissions.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:66)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6553)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6432)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Can anyone explain why does it crash? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Please edit your question and show the Java stack trace associated with the crash, along with any code tied to that crash that may not already be ni the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sir I added my logcat, and I found the problem. The problem was the Snackbar haha.. When I removed the SNACKBARS and replaced them with TOAST in the **onRequestPermissionsResult** it suddenly worked haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.
```

Presumably, that is from one of your two `Snackbar` references:

```
Snackbar.make(view,"Permission Granted, Now you can access location data.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

In both, you refer to a `view` field. I do not see where you are populating that field. You would need to assign `view` a valid `View` from your layout, usually obtained via `findViewById()`.

Or, as you apparently did, replace `Snackbar` with something else (e.g., `Toast`).

Comment: Yes sir, you are correct. Thanks for the help and explanation sir!

Answer (score 1):

```
        String [] permissions=new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        };
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String permission:permissions) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,permission )!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(permission);
            }
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), 1);
        }
```

Comment: Sir I found the problem. The problem was the Snackbar haha.. When I removed the SNACKBARS and replaced them with TOAST in the onRequestPermissionsResult it suddenly worked haha. Thanks again for the help sir. You deserve an upvote :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use your XML layout to view the snack-bar. This problem occurs when the snack-bar don't have a view to view its view. So we should tell it to view yours in this layout. It can be whatever layout. For an example, I use linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/ll_container"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Use linear layout's id and tell snack-bar to view on it like below

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayoutContainer = v.findViewById(R.id.ll_container)

Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(mLinearLayoutContainer, "your text here.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite))
                    .setAction(getResources().getString(R.string.label_settings), new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                        }
                    });

            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
            snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Snackbar.make(view,"Permission Granted, Now you can access location data.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

instead of using this try using the one below,

```
 Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.container_view),"Permission Granted, Now you can access location data.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It worked for me.